# turning borders into images using css?

Tags: html, css, image, border

for example

```
 #footer .tri{
     border-color:transparent transparent #212121;
```

into this :

```
#footer .tri{
 border-color:transparent transparent url("border-image.png");
```

deos that actually work!! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out CSS3's [`border-image`](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) property, which does exactly what you want. As with many other CSS3 styles, this is only supported by modern browsers. Unfortunately, this is not supported even by IE9.

Comment: +1 not in all browsers yet, however. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html

Comment: @getaway: Then use `border-bottom-image`.